# how to mistake domain with dot direct to correct domain

Tags: php, url, redirect

Im PHP user... =) How can i make correct forward to right domain after people wrong typing?

Example:

Wrong URL:

```
http://www.somedomain.com.
http://www.somedomain.com./
http://www.somedomain.com,
http://www.somedomain.com,/
```

forward to proper:

```
http://www.somedomain.com
```

edited: Im PHP user...

Comment: Forward? Where are those domains coming from? Are they entered into a program? If so into which kind of program?

Comment: You should better describe your question. E.g. give the one URL with the dot after the domain name and say it does not load like w/o. I think that's your main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer...

here's my solution: (For PHP user)

```
if ('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/' == 'http://'.substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,-1).'./')
{
    if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != null)
    {
        $QUERYSTRING = '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }

    header('Location: http://'.substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,-1).$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].$QUERYSTRING);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first two are not wrong. For the second two, rewrite the browser.

Answer (score 2):

If they make that mistake then its out of your hand. The DNS lookup will fail and they will never make it to your site to be redirected anywhere.

Although depending on the browser, it might correct the URL for them, but that is still out of your control and by the time they get to your site they will have the correct domain name.

Comment: but my site still work with dot but all images not showing up even also no good with $_GET

Comment: Which browser are you using? Firefox?

Comment: How are you creating your image URLS?

Comment: i checked with chrome, opera i think all browser works with dot =/

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about domain names that are entered into an internet browser, you need to control the DNS server that is used by either that browser or the system that is running the browser. That could be done with DNS forwarding then.

As an alternative, you can extend the browser with that functionality.

PHP running on your server has almost nothing to do with that.